# How to retrieve multiple detail records plus the master record as a single row?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, crosstab

I have two tables with a structure similar to this:

Person:

```
ID   Name   Age
 1   Jack    25
 2   Jill    23
```

Tests:

```
ID  PersonID  TestID  Result
 1         1       1     125
 2         1       2     120
 3         1       3      75
 4         2       1      90
 5         2       2      95
 6         2       3     7.2
```

Is there a way to retrieve that data with a single statement in a way that each record in the master table is presented in a single row? Something like this:

```
PersonID  Name  Age  Test1  Test2  Test3
       1  Jack   25    125    120     75
       2  Jill   23     90     95    7.2
```

So far, the only way I have come up with has been to create a function which iterates through the detail records and fills a temporary table. Not very elegant.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm using a function like this http://www.itrain.de/knowhow/sql/tsql/pivot/sp_transform_v1_1.asp 
but mine would be oversized for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get this result, you will need to use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function. This transforms the data from multiple rows into columns.

If you know the values ahead of time or you will have a limited number of `TestId` values, then you can hard-code the query making the query static.

```
SELECT Name,
  Age,
  [1] AS Test1,
  [2] AS Test2,
  [3] AS Test3 
FROM
( 
  SELECT P.Name, P.Age, t.TestID, t.Result 
  FROM tests t
  INNER JOIN person P 
  ON p.ID = t.PersonID
) T 
PIVOT
(
  sum(Result) 
  FOR TestID IN ([1], [2], [3])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf74c/7).

But if you have an unknown number of `TestId` values, then you will want to use dynamic SQL to generate the list of columns at run-time. You Code will be:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(testId) 
                    from tests
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

select @colNames = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(testId) +' as Test'+cast(testId as varchar(10))
                    from tests
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Name, age, ' + @colnames + ' from 
             (
                select P.Name, P.Age, t.TestID, t.Result 
                from tests t
                inner join person P 
                  on p.ID = t.PersonID
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(Result)
                for TestID in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf74c/6).

They both will generate the same result, difference being that the dynamic one will increase/decrease the columns if the number of test ids changes:

```
| NAME | AGE | TEST1 | TEST2 | TEST3 |
--------------------------------------
| Jack |  25 |   125 |   120 |    75 |
| Jill |  23 |    90 |    95 |   7.2 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a pivot on the TestID

Here you go... its kinda messy but you can improve on it :)

```
SELECT Name,Age,SUM([1]) AS Test1,SUM([2]) AS Test2,SUM([3]) AS Test3
FROM(
SELECT P.Name,P.Age,Te.ID, TestID,Result
FROM Test Te
INNER JOIN dbo.Person P ON P.ID=Te.PersonID) T
PIVOT(MAX(T.Result) FOR TestID IN([1],[2],[3])) AS pvt
GROUP BY Name,Age
```

heres some links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/393632/How-to-use-Pivot-in-SQL
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/

Comment: I'm lost. Can you write an statement for the data I've provided here please?

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use a similar statement when the number of detail records is not known beforehand?